# C++ Trying to sort an array of classes by their average then rank them in increasing order

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting

This is for a project in class and Ive been stuck for hours. The assignment is to open a text file containing a list of student names their ID numbers and their scores on different quizes, midterms, and finals then calculate the average. We have to make a class for each student then calculate the average for each student and give ranks to the student based on who got the best grade. So far I have created a class for each student and found the average and ranked the students averages from greatest to least but I cant figure out how to assign ranks. Here is a picture of the assignment if you want more information : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wQyp.jpg

And here is my code:

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <cstring>
            #include <string>
            #include <fstream>
            #include <algorithm>
            #include <functional>
            using namespace std;

            int num_a = 0, num_b = 0, num_c = 0, num_d = 0, num_f = 0;

            class Student {
            private:
            int rank;
            string name;
            int id;
            double quiz_scores[5];
            double midterm_scores[2];
            double final_score;
            double average;
            double quiz_average;
            double midterm_average;
            char grade;


            public:
            Student();
            void setRank(int num);
            int getRank();
            void setGrade(double average);
            char getGrade();
            void setName(string first);
            string getName();
            void setId(int num);
            int getId();
            void setMidterms(double nums[]);
            double getMidterms();
            void setQuizes(double nums[]);
            double getQuizes();
            void setFinal(double num);
            double getFinal();
            void setAverage();
            double getAverage();

            };
            Student::Student()
            {
            name = "John Doe";
            id = 0;
            final_score = 0;
            average = 0;
            grade = 'F';
            midterm_scores[2] = {};
            quiz_scores[5] = {};
            rank = 0;
            }
            void Student::setRank(int num)
            {
                rank = num;
            }
            int Student::getRank()
            {
                return rank;
            }
            void Student::setGrade(double average)
            {
            if (average <= 100 && average >= 90)
            {
            grade = 'A';
            num_a++;
            }
            else if (average <= 89.99 && average >= 80)
            {
            grade = 'B';
            num_b++;
            }
            else if (average <= 79.99 && average >= 70)
            {
            grade = 'C';
            num_c++;
            }
            else if (average <= 69.99 && average >= 60)
            {
            grade = 'D';
            num_d++;
            }
            else if (average < 60)
            grade = 'F';
            num_f++;
            }
            void Student::setName(string first)
            {
            name = first;
            }
            string Student::getName()
            {
            return name;
            }
            void Student::setId(int num)
            {
            id = num;
            }
            int Student::getId()
            {
            return id;
            }
            void Student::setMidterms(double nums[])
            {
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(1);

            double average, sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
            midterm_scores[i] = nums[i];
            sum += midterm_scores[i];
            }

            average = sum / 2;
            midterm_average = average * .40;

            }
            double Student::getMidterms()
            {
            return midterm_average;
            }
            void Student::setQuizes(double nums[])
            {
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(1);

            double score, sum = 0, average, min = nums[0];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (nums[i] < min)
            {
            min = nums[i];
            }

            score = nums[i];
            quiz_scores[i] = score;
            sum += quiz_scores[i];
            }
            sum = sum - min;
            average = (sum / 40) * 100;
            quiz_average = average * .20 ;

            }
            double Student::getQuizes()
            {
            return quiz_average;
            }
            void Student::setAverage()
            {
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(1);

            average = (quiz_average + midterm_average + final_score);
            }
            void Student::setFinal(double num)
            {
            cout.setf(ios::fixed);
            cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
            cout.precision(1);

            final_score = num * .40;
            }
            double Student::getFinal()
            {
            return final_score;
            }
            double Student::getAverage()
            {
            return average;
            }

            char Student::getGrade()
            {
            return grade;
            }
            //ranks the student by decreasing average grade
            void rankStudents(double array[], int arraySize, Student scores[])
            {
                int m; // keep the index of current smallest value
                double newArray[30], hold, finalArray[30];
                bool isFound = false;
                //stores the averages in an array then sorts array
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    newArray[i] = array[i];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k <= arraySize - 2; k++)
                {
                    m = k;
                    for (int j = k + 1; j <= arraySize - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (newArray[j] > newArray[m])
                            m = j;
                    }

                    hold = newArray[m];
                    newArray[m] = newArray[k];
                    newArray[k] = hold;
                }

                //assigns rank to each student by comparing the array of averages to the students average by calling student.getAverage()
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    double test = newArray[i];
                    int counter = i;
                    for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++)
                    {
                        int counter2 = i;
                        if (scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            scores[k].setRank(counter+1);
                        }
                        else if (scores[k].getAverage() == scores[k - 1].getAverage() && scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            scores[k].setRank(i + 1);
                            scores[k - 1].setRank(scores[k].getRank());
                        }
                        //cout << scores[k].getName() << ' ' << scores[k].getId() << ' ' << scores[k].getRank() << endl;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    //cout << scores[i].getName() << ' ' << scores[i].getId() << ' ' << scores[i].getAverage() << ' ' << scores[i].getGrade() << ' ' << scores[i].getRank() << endl;
                }
                //creates finalArray which stores the students ranks and sorts them
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    finalArray[i] = scores[i].getRank();
                }
                for (int k = 0; k <= arraySize - 2; k++)
                {
                    m = k;
                    for (int j = k + 1; j <= arraySize - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (finalArray[j] < finalArray[m])
                            m = j;
                    }

                    hold = finalArray[m];
                    finalArray[m] = finalArray[k];
                    finalArray[k] = hold;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    //cout << scores[i].getRank() << endl;
                }
                //prints out the array
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    double test = newArray[i];
                    int counter3 = i;
                    for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++)
                    {
                        if (scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            cout << scores[k].getName() << ' ' << scores[k].getId() << ' ' <<  scores[k].getAverage() << ' ' <<scores[k].getGrade() << ' ' << scores[k].getRank() << endl;
                        }
                        if (scores[k].getAverage() == scores[k - 1].getAverage() && scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            scores[k].setRank(i + 1);
                            scores[k - 1].setRank(scores[k].getRank());
                            cout << scores[k].getName() << ' ' << scores[k].getId() << ' ' << scores[k].getAverage() << ' ' << scores[k].getGrade() << ' ' << scores[k].getRank() << endl;
                        }
                    }

                }


            }

            void readFile(Student people[])
            {
                //declares input file
                ifstream in_file;
                string user_file;
                int number_of_students, id;

                double quiz1, quiz2, quiz3, quiz4, quiz5, midterm1, midterm2, final_score, quizes[5], midterm[2], averages[30];
                string name;
                cout << "Enter an input file: ";
                cin >> user_file;

                in_file.open(user_file);
                if (in_file.fail())
                {
                    cout << "Error: file open failed \n" << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }

                //finds number of players in the array
                in_file >> number_of_students;


                //creates an array for scores then stores the id and scores of each player
                for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
                {
                    in_file >> name >> id >> quiz1 >> quiz2 >> quiz3 >> quiz4 >> quiz5 >> midterm1 >> midterm2 >> final_score;
                    people[i].setName(name);
                    people[i].setId(id);
                    quizes[0] = quiz1;
                    quizes[1] = quiz2;
                    quizes[2] = quiz3;
                    quizes[3] = quiz4;
                    quizes[4] = quiz5;
                    midterm[0] = midterm1;
                    midterm[1] = midterm2;
                    people[i].setQuizes(quizes);
                    people[i].setMidterms(midterm);
                    people[i].setFinal(final_score);
                    //cout << array[i].getName() << " quiz average = " << array[i].getQuizes() << "midterm average = " << array[i].getMidterms() << "final = " << array[i].getFinal() << endl;
                    people[i].setAverage();
                    people[i].setGrade(people[i].getAverage());
                    //cout << array[i].getAverage() << endl;
                    averages[i] = people[i].getAverage();
                    //cout << averages[i] << endl;


                    //cout << "grade = " << array[i].getGrade() << endl;

                    //calls findAverage function to find average of each array then stores the result in player class



                }
                rankStudents(averages, number_of_students, people);

                for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
                {
                    if (people[i].getAverage() == averages[i])
                        people[i].setRank(i);

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < number_of_students; i++)
                {
                    cout << people[i].getRank();
                }

            }
            int main()
            {

            Student students[30];
            readFile(students);




            return 0;
            }
```

This is the part i need help on:

```
            void rankStudents(double array[], int arraySize, Student scores[])
            {
                int m; // keep the index of current smallest value
                double newArray[30], hold, finalArray[30];
                bool isFound = false;
                //stores the averages in an array then sorts array
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    newArray[i] = array[i];
                }

                for (int k = 0; k <= arraySize - 2; k++)
                {
                    m = k;
                    for (int j = k + 1; j <= arraySize - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (newArray[j] > newArray[m])
                            m = j;
                    }

                    hold = newArray[m];
                    newArray[m] = newArray[k];
                    newArray[k] = hold;
                }

                //assigns rank to each student by comparing the array of averages to the students average by calling student.getAverage()
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    double test = newArray[i];
                    int counter = i;
                    for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++)
                    {
                        int counter2 = i;
                        if (scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            scores[k].setRank(counter+1);
                        }
                        else if (scores[k].getAverage() == scores[k - 1].getAverage() && scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            scores[k].setRank(i + 1);
                            scores[k - 1].setRank(scores[k].getRank());
                        }
                        //cout << scores[k].getName() << ' ' << scores[k].getId() << ' ' << scores[k].getRank() << endl;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    //cout << scores[i].getName() << ' ' << scores[i].getId() << ' ' << scores[i].getAverage() << ' ' << scores[i].getGrade() << ' ' << scores[i].getRank() << endl;
                }
                //creates finalArray which stores the students ranks and sorts them
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    finalArray[i] = scores[i].getRank();
                }
                for (int k = 0; k <= arraySize - 2; k++)
                {
                    m = k;
                    for (int j = k + 1; j <= arraySize - 1; j++)
                    {
                        if (finalArray[j] < finalArray[m])
                            m = j;
                    }

                    hold = finalArray[m];
                    finalArray[m] = finalArray[k];
                    finalArray[k] = hold;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    //cout << scores[i].getRank() << endl;
                }
                //prints out the array
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
                {
                    double test = newArray[i];
                    int counter3 = i;
                    for (int k = 0; k < arraySize; k++)
                    {
                        if (scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            cout << scores[k].getName() << ' ' << scores[k].getId() << ' ' <<  scores[k].getAverage() << ' ' <<scores[k].getGrade() << ' ' << scores[k].getRank() << endl;
                        }
                        if (scores[k].getAverage() == scores[k - 1].getAverage() && scores[k].getAverage() == test)
                        {
                            scores[k].setRank(i + 1);
                            scores[k - 1].setRank(scores[k].getRank());
                            cout << scores[k].getName() << ' ' << scores[k].getId() << ' ' << scores[k].getAverage() << ' ' << scores[k].getGrade() << ' ' << scores[k].getRank() << endl;
                        }
                    }

                }


            }
```

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you review whatever notes you have on array subscripting in C++, because beyond the sorting issues, you're invoking *undefined* behavior in multiple places. Ex: both `midterm_scores[2] = {};` and `quiz_scores[5] = {};` are (a) not doing what you think they are, and (b) both writing one-past the actual declared size of the respective arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the scores by using the `std` `sort()` function by giving it an iterator to the beginning of the array as the first parameter and an iterator to the end of the array as the second parameter. More on [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

Then, you can iterate through your sorted average scores and give a score based on a decrementing basis. For example, your highest score will be given rank 1. Go to the next score. Check if the score is the same as the previous. If it is, give the same rank, otherwise, increment your rank and then assign it.

Your ranking function is a bit convoluted.  I suggest you separate this into three parts. Get the averages, sort, then rank. I'd use vectors to facilitate things further. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks I didn't even think to check if the next score is the the same as the current I was using a whole loop to do that. And I know its overly complicated I showed it to my TA and she literally laughed then showed me the teachers version and the whole thing was done in 4 lines of code :)

Comment: Indeed, the std::sort idea seems quite interesting. In your particular case, you could define a std::vector< Student >, fill it with your students, and add an operator< to your Student class, based on their grades. Then std::sort makes all the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you have done everything up to the last part, assigning grades ("Any average of 90 or more is an 'A',...").

I advise you to **isolate this part of the problem.** Write a function that takes a score and returns a letter. Once that's working perfectly, you can add that function to your code and fill in the `grade` field of each student.

The signature of the function should be something like this (until/unless you make it a member function or something):

```
char letterGrade(double score)
```

Is that enough to work with?